# Regex , First Two character as Alphabetic Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I Have a Dataframe as df and Column as Column1
If the column1 value is Not Applicable, Return False, or check wheteher first 2 characters of the element in the column should be alphabetic, And Return True or False

```
df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : False if x in ['Not Applicable'] else x[0:2] should be alphabetic)
```

How to check the the first two character is alphabetic in the else part of lambda function ?

Comment: Can you add sample with desired output?

Comment: I see no question here.

Comment: @VigneshwaranMarkandan he want to check if the first two caracter of x in the else of the apply are alphabetic

Comment: `x[0:2].isalpha()`

Comment: @Coldspeed Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution needs no regex. If you want to check that those 2 letters are alphabets, use the [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) function.

```
df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : False if x in ['Not Applicable'] else x[0:2].isalpha())
```

---

At OP's request, with [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

```
import re
df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : False if x in ['Not Applicable'] else re.match('[a-z]{2}', x[0:2].lower()) )
```

`re.match` returns a match object if there is a match, else will return `None`, so you can use the truthiness of the return value.

Comment: how can I do if i want use Regex Inside

Comment: @Shivpe_R Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`str.isalpha`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isalpha.html) and [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Not Applicable dds','*7df Not Applicable','sd ds', '#@( 444']})

df['a'] = np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('Not Applicable'), False,
                   df['col1'].str[:2].str.isalpha())
print (df)
                  col1      a
0   Not Applicable dds  False
1  *7df Not Applicable  False
2                sd ds   True
3              #@( 444  False
```